# Please help me understand \titleformat documentation

Tags: titlesec

I am trying to understand the `\titleformat` command. According to the documentation, the format is

`\titleformat{<command>}[<shape>]{<format>}{<label>}{<sep>}{<before-code>}[<after-code>]`

This may sound silly to you guys but I'm having hard time figuring out the `after-code`. The way it is defined in the [documentation](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/layout/titlesec.pdf) makes it sound like whatever is in that slot should just appear after the title body; however, when I write the following code,

```
\titleformat{\section}{\color{ForestGreen}}{\thesection.}{0.5cm}{Before}{After}
\section{TITLE}
```

this is what I get:

[image]

I'm not sure what's going on. I looked at the examples in the documentation appendix and the last slot was left blank in all the cases. I don't see myself supplying an argument there either but I'm just trying to understand what it's doing.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you! Also, I'm a beginner and have been using this site as a crutch since I started Latex-ing. lol. Thank you everyone for voluntarily answering so many questions here. This website + documentation is how I picked up/am learning Latex!

Comment: Uh it's just your typo. Look carefully, the last one is delimited with[] not {}

Comment: Although good job figuring out where the documentation is.

Comment: @user202729 dang it. haha. Thank you!